# Issue with z-index

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

So the right-hand flags ( on roll over ) get cut off by the box width. How do I get the flag to break out of that box or sit on top of it without changing the page structure ( only with CSS )?

http://www.erfolg-für-alle.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to delete overflow: hidden; from wall_container class, but then you have to add float: left, clear: both for div with id "p2".

Comment: Yup was just going to say that.. :)

Comment: @all Wow, that was soo obvious! can't believe I added the overflow hidden, hahaha! This is where SO shines, when simple oversights cause headaches!